# How to group a strongly typed model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, razor

I pass my model to my view.  On this view I am displaying a table and trying to populate it with a list of information from the database.

**I am using asp.net-mvc, entity framework, razor, c# and LINQ**

However I need it grouped by a certain column `kpiID`.

Here are all of the columns in the table.

```
kpiHistoryID
kpiID
startAmount
completedamount
endAmount
completeBy
comments
```

The kpiID links back the the KPI table and is where I can grab the actual name of the KPI.

How exactly do I group the data and can it be done in the below `@foreach` line?

```
 <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in @Model.IPACS_Department.IPACS_Functions.SelectMany(m => m.IPACS_Processes).SelectMany(m => m.IPACS_Procedures).SelectMany(m => m.IPACS_KPIS).SelectMany(m => m.IPACS_kpiHistory))
    {
        <tr class="gradeX">
            <td>
                @item.IPACS_KPIS.name
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.startAmount
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.completedAmount
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.endAmount
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: You should be doing the `SelectMany` stuff any grouping in the controller, so the View just has to loop though `var item in Model.TheList`

Comment: @ColmPrunty You're correct.  However I'm not super experienced.  On this page I need access to the IPACS_Department, IPACS_Function, IPACS_Process, IPACS_Procedure, IPACS_KPIS and IPACS_kpiHistory.  I supposed I could set them all in the controller, but still don't know how to group them correctly.

Comment: This is what view models are for. Use them. *Always* use them. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3fundamentals_topic7.aspx

Comment: How is IPACS_Functions related to kpiId?

Comment: @AntP I understand that, however I do not have the time to rewrite how it was done.  I do have the time to make a requested modification to it however.  All I need are how to group the IPACS_kpiHistory data by name.

Comment: @ColmPrunty I have 5 tables.  Department -> Functions -> Processes -> Procedures -> KPI's.  They are one to many in that order.  This is the `departmentView` page so we are looking at the data from the highest level which is why in the above table I have to dive deep through the model to get to the `kpiHistory` data.  `kpiHistory` had a `kpiID`, which has a `procedureID`, which has a `processID`, which has a `functionId`, which has `departmentID`.

Comment: And I assume KPI to KPI history is 1:1? Before thinking too hard about this, do you know that linq does have a GroupBy(x => x.something) function?

Comment: @ColmPrunty I tried to play around with the GrouBy, but when I wrote out the items it just displayed System.Linq. stuff instead of the values/text.  And yes they are 1:1.

Comment: @ColmPrunty Well actually kpiHistory can have multiple entries for an IPACS_KPIS entry.  So I need to display the kpihistory data grouped by the kpiID, or sum the Counts of the kpiHistory by kpiID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way I could figure out how to do it was using sum.  Couldn't get it to work with group by at all.

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in @Model.IPACS_Department.IPACS_Functions.SelectMany(m => m.IPACS_Processes).SelectMany(m => m.IPACS_Procedures).SelectMany(m => m.IPACS_KPIS))
    {
        <tr class="gradeX">
            <td>
                @item.name
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.IPACS_kpiHistory.Select(m => m.startAmount).Sum()
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.IPACS_kpiHistory.Select(m => m.completedAmount).Sum()
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.IPACS_kpiHistory.Select(m => m.endAmount).Sum()
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
@Model.IPACS_Department.IPACS_Functions.SelectMany(m => m.IPACS_Processes)
.SelectMany(m => m.IPACS_Procedures).SelectMany(m => m.IPACS_KPIS)
.SelectMany(m => m.IPACS_kpiHistory)
```

gives a list of denormalised kpiHistories, yes? Does it not give you the answer you want if you do

```
thatList.GroupBy(x => x.kpiID)
```

Comment: I couldn't get thatList.GroupBy to even show an option for GroupBy.  but I was able to guess a way to do what I needed it to do.  Posted answer, not sure why I was having so much trouble with GroupBy.

Comment: Strange that GroupBy didn't come up as an option, but I guess if you've figured out what you want to do, that's enough. If you ever get curious enough to figure out what was up with GroupBy, post a comment for me.